# Different Headers and Footers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm stuck in the middle of a work. I want to have the author's name at the left side of an odd page (title page exclusive) and the journal's name at the right side on an even page but with the page number at the left.

This is the code I have.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small Frema et al: XXX}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small FOOD SCIENCE JOURNAL}
\fancyfoot[L,R,C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

The journal's name doesn't show on the even-numbered page, and also it gives me the message "fancyhdr e option without twoside option is useless on line 100."

How can I fix this?

Comment: The message is clear: if you want to have different headers on even and odd pages, you need to pass the `twoside` option to your document class.

Comment: As the warning says, your are typesetting the document as single-side. add `twoside` option to the main `documentclass` (or whatever the class you are using needs).

Comment: Worked. Appreciated guys